# Lucene.Net 4.8.0-beta00016 is throwing exception when i try to read FastTaxonomyFacetCounts from File Directory

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, lucene, lucene.net

I'm using Lucene.Net 4.8.0-beta00016 version and using .Net 6.0.
When i write to RAMDirectory i'm able to fetch FastTaxonomyFacetCounts if i try to fetch from Directory (File System) it is throwing Index Corrupted. Missing parent data for category 0.

Below is the code which I'm facing issue. IndexDirectory and TaxoDirectory is the physical file path where lucene indexes generated.

```
using (DirectoryReader indexReader = DirectoryReader.Open(IndexDirectory))
            using (DirectoryTaxonomyReader taxoReader = new DirectoryTaxonomyReader(TaxoDirectory))
            {
                IndexSearcher searcher = new IndexSearcher(indexReader);

                FacetsCollector fc = new FacetsCollector();

                Query q = new WildcardQuery(new Term("Brand", "*Ji*"));
                TopScoreDocCollector tdc = TopScoreDocCollector.Create(10, true);

                var topDocs = FacetsCollector.Search(searcher, q, 10, fc);
                var topHits = topDocs.ScoreDocs;

                var hits = searcher.Search(q, 10, Sort.INDEXORDER).ScoreDocs;
                if (hits != null)
                {
                    foreach (var hit in hits)
                    {
                        var document = searcher.Doc(hit.Doc);
                    }
                }
                Facets facets = new FastTaxonomyFacetCounts(taxoReader, config, fc);
                var result = facets.GetAllDims(1000);

            }
```

If anyone has solution. Please guide me

It should return Facets.

Comment: If you update your question to contain a unit test that demos the error using the smallest code possible then I can probably help you.  I've done a lot with facets, they can be tricky but they work great.

Comment: @RonC, the facets work with FSDirectory? It is working with RAMDirectory but throwing exception if I put FSDirectory to get data from physical files. Could you please help me?

Comment: I have facets working with `FSDirectory`, they work fine.  But facets are one of the more complicated features of Lucene and there are in fact two totally different implementations of facets.  One that can handle hierarchical categories and requires a 2nd "sidecar"  index and one implementation that does't handle them and does not require a 2nd sidecar index. Due to the complexity I need you to post a full snipit of code I can compile and see what you are seeing. So it needs to add the docs to the index and then build the facets and it needs to work with RAMDirectory and fail with FSDirectory.